# Creating directory in hdfs using oozie

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

In a oozie workflow how can we create a directory in `HDFS` and Copy files from `Linux` to `HDFS`

I want to do the following in workflow

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/$USER/logging/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/logs


hdfs dfs -put /home/$USER/logs/"${table}" /user/$USER/logging/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/logs/
```

How can I achieve that?

I have tried the following but without success

```
<action name="Copy_to_HDFS">
    <fs>
        <mkdir path='/user/$USER/logging/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/logs'/>
        <move source='/home/$USER/logs${table}' target='/user/$USER/logging/`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`/logs/'/>
    </fs>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="end"/>
</action>
```

How can we create a folder with the name of that particular date?

Full workflow:

```
    <workflow-app name="Shell_hive" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="shell-b8e7"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="shell-b8e7">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <exec>shell.sh</exec>
              <argument>${table}</argument>
           <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>
           <env-var>HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf</env-var>
           <file>/user/$USER/oozie/scripts/lib/shell.sh#shell.sh</file>   
        </shell>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <action name="Copy_to_HDFS">
        <fs>
            <mkdir path="/user/$USER/logging/2017-04-24/logs"/>
            <move source="/tmp/logging/${table}" target="/user/$USER/logging/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/logs/"/>
        </fs>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="end"/>
    </action>
        <end name="End"/>
    </workflow-app>
```

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Comment: @franklinsijo can we create directory using `timestamp` in workflow. Looks like the problem is with `date "+%Y-%m-%d"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the quotes, single quotes(`'`) block the variable expansion.

```
<action name="Copy_to_HDFS">
    <fs>
        <mkdir path="/user/$USER/logging/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/logs"/>
        <move source="/home/$USER/logs${table}" target="/user/$USER/logging/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/logs/"/>
    </fs>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="end"/>
</action>
```

**UPDATE:**
The `Copy_to_HDFS` action is never invoked. The action `shell-b8e7` on success is sent to `End` action. Modify the workflow accordingly to invoke the `Copy_to_HDFS` action. For example,

```
</shell>
<ok to="Copy_to_HDFS"/>
```

Comment: are you able to create directory if you replace the date with a string?

Comment: Any oozie exceptions?

Comment: @franklinsijo For me it is creating a folder like this `$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` in hdfs

Comment: Did you try surrounding it with backquotes `date +%Y-%m-%d` instead of `$(..)`?

Answer (score 0):

The prepare tag might help :

```
<prepare>
                <delete path="[PATH]"/>
                ...
                <mkdir path="[PATH]"/>
                ...
</prepare>
```